# undefined symbol: sqlite3_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

When I try to deploy my Rails application to an Apache server using Passenger, I get the following error in the logs:

```
undefined symbol: sqlite3_initialize
```

I get the same error when just running webrick using "rails s". How do I fix this? I'm using the latest Rails 3.0.9 and whatever the default SQLite is when running bundle install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed the sqlite3 gem as part of `bundle install`, but have you installed the SQLite library somewhere Ruby can find it?  Personally I'm stunned you got the gem to build, but if you're using some sort of bodged up sqlite install it's possible that `gem install` was able to find the headers, but the Ruby interpreter itself can't find the library to link against at runtime.

The long and the short of it is that you've made a mess of your system, and you're going to have a real learning experience cleaning it up.

Comment: Yeah, but my question was how to fix this. Do you have any idea on how to do this? I'd rather not reinstall the entire VPS since it's several hours of work.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to answer that, and I sincerely doubt you'll be able to provide enough information to make it possible beyond blind guesswork.  As I said, it'll be a learning experience for you.

Comment: This is unbelievable. I started over from scratch by re-installing everything including the OS itself and I still got the same issue.